# Relative to absolute url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view i have link like following

```
<%= link_to raw(truncate(strip_tags(record.sch.first.to_s + ': ' + record.name), :length => 120, :omission => "...")), (Figaro.env.base_url + record.named_url) %>
```

But as result this produces me link like

```
basedomain.com/(Figaro.env.base_url)/record.named_url
```

when i want it to be

```
(Figaro.env.base_url)/record.named_url
```

How do i make this like absolute, not relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to prepend "http://" to the url.

`<%= link_to raw(truncate(strip_tags(record.sch.first.to_s + ': ' + record.name), :length => 120, :omission => "...")), ('http://' + Figaro.env.base_url + record.named_url) %>`

Comment: Thanks, no idea how could i miss that

Answer (score 5):

Add `only_path: false` at the end:

```
<%= link_to raw(truncate(strip_tags(record.sch.first.to_s + ': ' + record.name), :length => 120, :omission => "...")), (Figaro.env.base_url + record.named_url), only_path: false %>
```